# I want to implement custom navigation bar but status leaves 20 pixels gap.Its not comming on custom navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

[image] 1. Completed order  my custom navigation bar.
 2. Active order is my UINavigation bar.
 3. I want my status bar looks like active order  navigation bar.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take uiview of size : screenwidth and 64 height.

Set background color as red.

add label for title and two buttons for search and add as desired place in that view.

And put this view at (0,0) position. so view's origin should be (0,0).

**Update :**

Your constraints should be like : top,leading,trailing and fixed height

top = view.top equalto superview.top with constant 0

leading = view.leading equalto superview.leadind with constant 0

trailing = superview.trailing equalto view.trailing with constant 0

fixed height = view.height equal to 64

Yo can check this from `size inspector`. click any constraint and click `size inspector`.

Make sure that when you giving(pin) constraints `constraint to margin` is unchecked.

check the screenshot

[image]

Hope this will help :)

Comment: i have already taken uiview with 64 height and set its background color red but when i run my app status bar takes 20 pixels and down my view by 20 pixels

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: I am using autolayout

Comment: Which constraints have you set to that view?

Comment: Top , Leading , Trailing, bottom to tableview  and Height fixed .

Comment: can you post your view hierarchy and constraint's screenshot from document outline ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use autolayout:

First set your header view y = 0 position and after give all constraint.

or

your top constraint constant value set -12.

Answer (score 0):

While adding constraints from interface builder check mark Constrain to margin and update top constraint to 0. I hope this will work.[image]